# Match map's borders to graticule in QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, grids-graticules

I'm using QGIS v.3.22.0.
I've been going crazy trying to adjust a map size to match a graticule in the Print Layout.
I don't want to have any squares cut in the middle.
I don't want to adjust the grid to match the map size obviously, because that would change the interval I want to use in the grid.

All I want is to be able to adjust the map's dimensions in such a way that it matches the grid. The problem is when I try to do this manually, it automatically zooms, changes the scale, and changes the grid.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you set a fixed scale for the map using "Map Properties > Scale > Data defined override button > Edit", you can adjust the map borders to match the grid.

[image]